# React: Trying to create a custom firebase db.collection using the firebase.auth uid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-authentication

I cannot pass the uid to my db.collectionn('') function.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my SignUp component

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import SimpleReactValidator from "simple-react-validator";
import {toast} from "react-toastify";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import {Link, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from '../../context/AuthContext';
import { db } from '../../firebase/firebase';
import './style.scss';

const SignUpPage = (props) => {

    const { signUp, currentUser } = useAuth();    
    const push = useNavigate();
    //const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [buttonVisibility, setButtonVisibility] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState({});

    const submitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        passwordMatch();
        /*if (validator.allValid()) {
            setValue({
                email: '',
                full_name: '',
                password: '',
                confirm_password: '',
            });*/
            //validator.hideMessages();
            //success
            try{
                if (textValidator.allValid()) {               
                setError('');
                setButtonVisibility(true);
                console.log('passed email ' + value.email + 'passed password ' + value.password)
                let specialuuId = await signUp(value.email, value.password);
                console.log('auth created');                
                console.log('SignUp currentUser.uid#### ' + specialuuId);                
                await db.collection('usersCollection').document(specialuuId).setData({
                    email: value.email,
                    firstName: value.first_name,
                    lastName: value.last_name
                });
                console.log('db linked');
                setValue({
                    first_name: '',
                    last_name_name: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    confirm_password: '',
                });
                toast.success('Registration Complete successfully!');             
                push('/login');           
                }
                } catch {
                    toast.error('Failed to create an account');               
            }
            setButtonVisibility(false);
        };
```

Here is my AuthContext cmp

```
import { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import   { auth } from '../firebase/firebase';

const formatAuthUser = (user) => ({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName
  });

const AuthContext = createContext({
    authUser: null,
    loading: true,
    signUp: async () => {}
}) 

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export function AuthProvider({children}) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    //const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');

    const authStateChanged = async (authState) => {
        if (!authState) {
            setCurrentUser(null);
            setLoading(false);
            return;
            }
        setLoading(true)
        var formattedUser = formatAuthUser(authState);
        setCurrentUser(formattedUser);    
        setLoading(false);
      };

    const signUp = async (email, password) => {
        let uuid;
        await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) =>{
        uuid = user.user.uid;
        console.log('uudi#### ' + uuid);
        return uuid;
        })
    }

    const signIn = (email, password) => {
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    const signOut = () => {
        return auth.signOut();
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(authStateChanged)
        return unsubscribe;
    },[]);

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        loading,
        signIn,
        signUp,
        signOut,
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I see my uuid is establish in AuthContext cmp, but it never get return to signUp cmp
it shows as undefined in console.log
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHBrh.png)

I was expecting that consolo.log shows uuid here

```
let specialuuId = await signUp(value.email, value.password);
console.log('auth created');                
console.log('SignUp currentUser.uid#### ' + specialuuId);
```

Comment: Don't mix `async` / `await` with `.then()`. It just makes code confusing. Also, indent your code properly so you and anyone else can understand it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signUp function always returns undefined.  Here it is more properly formatted:

```
const signUp = async (email, password) => {
    let uuid;
    await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) =>{
            uuid = user.user.uid;
            console.log('uudi#### ' + uuid);
            return uuid;
        })
```

That `return` in the callback isn't returning from signUp.  It's only returning from the callback function you passed to `then` and not outside of that.  There is nothing returning any value from `signUp`, which is why you always get undefined.

Since you're using async/await, you don't need to use `then` at all.  In fact, it's almost always a programming error to mix then with async/await. Do this instead:

```
const signUp = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    const uuid = user.user.uid;
    console.log('uudi#### ' + uuid);
    return uuid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, 
When is appropriate to use .then()? feel free to share a link below